# Как меня отследили через вконтакте

Tags: php, javascript, вконтакте

Я посетил сайт pppp.com и через несколько дней мне пишет их менеджер и предлагает заказать услуги. Я немного удивился и спросил, а как они собственно на меня вышли? В ответ услышал фразу, что мол вот у нас система собирает все id пользователей, которые вошли на сайт. Стало интересно, как это так получается. Вначале, думал что куки как-то смотрят, там указан id, но в результате нашел несколько сервисов, которые такие услуги предлагают в коммерческом масштабе (по сбору id-адресов в вк и прочих сетях.). Отсюда 2 вопроса:
1) Как защититься.
2) Каков принцип действия данной системы? Каким образом, можно получить данные о том, какая страница ВК сейчас активна у посетителя сайта?

Comment: 1. Ходите на важные для вас сайты с отдельного браузера. P.S. Или лучше с отдельного компьютера ;)

Comment: правильный совет немного другой - не используйте вконтакт. Просто удалите аккаунт и все.

А действуют по разному - кто договаривается с вконтактом и платит за это деньги, кто то добавляет виджеты вконтакта, которые немного  "доделывают".

Comment: @KoVadim Интересно, а каков же сам по себе механизм этих модернизаций виджетов? Это ведь по идее не очень-то и законно.

Comment: я где то на хабре встречал подобное. Например, самое простое - просят залогиться вк аккаунтом. Но показывают не вк окно логина, а свое, которое также выглядит, как и стандартное.

Comment: @Rolandius а есть инфо по этому api? Хотелось бы увидеть своими глазами. А то, смахивает на какую-то серую схему.

Comment: @anj1817 если касаться сайта клиенту не надо - то зачем у самих этих ребят внизу форма для связи с ними? пусть бы связывались через контакт - они ж его отслеживают! :)

Comment: скорее всего обычный clickjacking. или отслеживание через приложение. или еще через какую-нибудь дыру.

Comment: @PashaPash Да! Вы правы, именно этот вопрос меня и пугал! Выходит эти коды есть в открытом доступе =(((
Теперь ясно чего бояться. Спасибо Вам. Если напишете свой предыдущий пост в ответы - зачту как правильный.

А вот насчет защиты - к сожалению информации пока нет =(

Comment: В браузере открыть окно в режиме инкогнито